# How to implement "fallback condition" in while loop in Expect?

Tags: while-loop, expect

I have a machine I telnet into, and pass "ctrl+C" until I see the prompt. The ctrl+C may not always work, so I must try after every 5 seconds until I see my expected output ($prompt).

In case I don't get a $prompt, how do I ensure I can retry the while loop effectively? Is this code below the best practice? My concern is, that I don't know what I may get when the "ctrl+C" fails, it could be anything and it must be ignored unless it's $prompt.

```
while { $disableFlag == 0 } {
    send "^C\r"
    expect {
                "*$prompt*" {
                    puts "Found the prompt"
                    sleep 5
                }
                "*" {
                    set disableFlag 1
                    puts "Retrying"
                    sleep 5
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this (untested)

```
set timeout 5
send \03
expect {
    "*$prompt*" {
        puts "found the prompt"
    }
    timeout {
        puts "did not see prompt within $timeout seconds. Retrying"
        send \03
        exp_continue
    }
}

# do something after seeing the prompt
```

`\03` is the octal value for ctrl-C: see http://wiki.tcl.tk/3038

If you want to bail out eventually:

```
set timeout 5
set count 0
send \03
expect {
    "*$prompt*" {
        puts "found the prompt"
    }
    timeout {
        if {[incr count] == 10} {  # die
            error "did not see prompt after [expr {$timeout * $count}] seconds. Aborting"
        }
        puts "did not see prompt within $timeout seconds. Retrying"
        send \03
        exp_continue
    }
}
```